# TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined at Object.module.exports.run

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to make a tempmute command which saves data to JSON then reads it every 3 seconds to see is the time experied. I made the mute command but I recive an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined`. I delete the `if(!message.member.roles.has("675376537272582154")) return message.channel.send('Bu komutu kullanabilmek için`「」Mute Premission `rolüne sahip olmasınız.')` but this time it said `TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined`. Can someone help me?

**Information**

Discord.js Version: v11.6.1

Node.js Version: 12.0.0

**Code**

```js
const { RichEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports.run = async (message, args, bot) => {

  if(!message.member.roles.has("675376537272582154")) return message.channel.send(`Bu komutu kullanabilmek için \`「」Mute Premission\` rolüne sahip olmasınız.`);

  let toMute = message.mentions.member.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0])
  if(!toMute) return message.channel.send(`:x: Susturulacak kullanıcıyı etiketlemelisin!`)

  let timeMute = args[1]
  if(!timeMute) return message.channel.send(':x: Susturma süresini dakika cinsinden yazmalısın!')
  if(isNaN(args[1])) return message.channel.send(':x: Senin de bildiğin gibi süre sadece sayı olabilir!')

  let reason = args.slice(2).join(" ")
  if(!reason) return message.channel.send(':x: Susturma sebebini yazmalısın!')

  if(toMute.id === message.author.id) return message.channel.send(`:x: Kendini susturamazsın bea!`)
  if(toMute.roles.has('675376537272582154')) return message.channel.send(`:x: \`「」Mute Premission\` rolüne sahip olan birini susturamazsın!`)

  let role = message.guild.roles.find(x => x.name === '「」Muted')
  if(!role) return message.channel.send(':x: `「」Muted` adlı rolü bulamıyorum!')

  if(toMute.roles.has(role.id)) return message.channel.send(':x: Bu kullanıcı zaten susturulmuş!')

  let modlog = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name === '『』punishment')
  if(!modlog) return message.channel.send(':x: Mod-Log kanalını bulamıyorum!')

  const embed = new RichEmbed()
  .setTitle('Susturma')
  //.setThumbnail(`${toMute.avatarURL}`)
  .setDescription(`**Susturlan Kişi: \`${toMute.tag}\`** \n **ID Numarası: \`${toMute.id}\`**\n **Susturan Yetkili: \`${message.author.tag}\`**\n **Süre: \`${timeMute}\`** **Sebep: \`${reason}\`** `)
  .setColor("#ff0000")
  .setFooter('Kurallara Uymayanın Sonu')
  .setTimestamp();

  bot.mutes[toMute.id] = {
    guild: message.guild.id,
    time: Date.now() + parseInt(args[1]) * 10000
  }

  await toMute.addRole(role)

  fs.writeFile("./mutes.json", JSON.stringify(bot.mutes, null, 4), err => {
   if(err) throw err;
   modlog.send(embed)
  })

}

module.exports.conf = {
  enabled: true,
  guildOnly: true,
  aliases: ['sustur'],
  permLevel: 0
};

module.exports.help = {
  name: 'mute',
  description: 'Sustur gitsin',
  usage: '!sustur @kullanıcı süre sebep'  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`member` and `guild` are most likely undefined because your bot is receiving a DM message. Check if the message is from a guild before continuing with your code:

```js
module.exports.run = async (message, args, bot) => {
  if(!message.guild) return
  // rest of code
}
```

Comment: I just tried it, but it didn't work. This time I don't recive an error but it is still same. I am using the command in a guild, not DM. Then I add ```if(!message.guild) return message.channel.send('Hey, this command is guild only!')``` but this time I got `Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`

Comment: @BloodStains Are you using [paritals](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/partials.html) by any chance? That might be why `message.channel` is `undefined`. If not, could you please edit your question to include what you're passing in for `message` to the `run` function?